# How does spark infers numeric types from JSON?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to create a DataFrame from a JSON file, but when I load data, spark automatically infers that the numeric values in the data are of type Long, although they are actually Integers, and this is also how I parse the data in my code.

Since I'm loading the data in a test env, I don't mind using a few workarounds to fix the schema. I've tried more than a few, such as:

- Changing the schema manually
- Casting the data using a UDF
- Define the entire schema manually

The issue is that the schema is quite complex, and the fields I'm after are nested, which makes all of the options above irrelevant or too complex to write from scratch.

My main question is, how does spark decides if a numeric value is an Integer or Long? and is there anything I can do to enforce that all\some numerics are of a specific type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always LongType by default.

From the source code:

```
// For Integer values, use LongType by default.
case INT | LONG => LongType
```

So you cannot change this behaviour. You can iterate by columns and then do casting:

```
for (c <- schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType])) {
    df.withColumn(c.name, col(c.name).cast(IntegerType))
}
```

It's only a snippet, but something like this should help you :)